# System.out.println() is a method to a field?

Tags: java

if out is a field to the System class. how is it that you can use println() method in a field? and where does this println() method come from, i cant find it in the System class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since `System.out` is a (reference to an instance of) PrintStream,
we can write `System.out.println()` as:

```
    PrintStream output = System.out;
    output.println();
```

Answer (score 8):

`System.out` is a public instance of the `PrintStream` class:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Answer (score 4):

`in`, `out`, and `err` are all public static fields of `java.lang.System`.  There's nothing preventing you from marking a field as `public`, although generally it is considered bad form (use getters and setters instead).

`System.out` is of type `PrintStream`, which provides the `println` method.

See as a starting point: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out

Comment: It is only a bad form if it was not `static final`.

Comment: Good catch!  Indeed, I had forgotten that they were declared `static final` since they can be changed with `setOut()`.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` is of type `PrintStream`, which has a `println()` method.

You can see all the methods of `PrintStream` at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html.

And here are the fields and methods of System:  http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

More generally, a field is just a member of an `Object`, so it can be of any type.  If it's a public field then it is accessible to the client code, though generally it's considered better practice to make fields accessible through getter methods as opposed to directly (but in this case, imagine if you had to write `System.getOut().println()` every time you wanted to write to standard output!).

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` is a member of `System`, alright, but is is also a reference to a `PrintStream` instance.  From the source:

```
public final static PrintStream out = nullPrintStream();
```

`PrintStream` is a class in `java.io`, and has the method `println()`.  See the JavaDocs for [`java.io.PrintStream.println()`](http://www.ermalaev.spb.ru/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)) for more details.

Comment: so java.io.PrintStream.println() is exactly the same as java.lang.System.out.println() ?

Comment: Not exactly.  With the first, `java.io.PrintStream.println()` is the fully qualified method name--`java.io` is the package, PrintStream is the *class*, and `println()` is a method on that class.  *With the later*, it is different.  java.lang.System.out.println() does not exist.  Rather, java.lang.System has a member (a variable) named `out` of type `PrintStream` with an instance of a `PrintStream` class assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

If a field is public and is an `Object`, there is nothing surprising in being able to call a method on it. Why would it be?

In the particular case of the [`System`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) class, the [`out`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) field is a public static field of type [`PrintStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) (it holds an instance of a [`PrintStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) statically which has a [`println()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) method) and this is what the javadoc says about it:

> The "standard" output stream. This
>   stream is already open and ready to
>   accept output data. Typically this
>   stream corresponds to display output
>   or another output destination
>   specified by the host environment or
>   user.
>
> For simple stand-alone Java
>   applications, a typical way to write a
>   line of output data is:
>
> ```
>      System.out.println(data)
> ```
>
> See the `println` methods in class
>   `PrintStream`.

Answer (score 1):

`System` is a class as you know and `out` is a static variable of class `System` of type `PrintStream` i.e inside `System` class, `out` is declared as :

```
public static final PrintStream out;
```

That also means `out` is an instance of class `PrintStream` so it can access methods defined in class `PrintStream`.

So as we are accessing static variable `out` outside class `System` we write

```
System.out
```

and to access methods like `print` or `println` of class `PrintStream` we write

```
System.out.print()
```

as `System.out` (or `out`) is nothing but a variable pointing to an object of class `PrintStream` as said above.

We could also write

```
Printstream john;  
john = new Printstream();
john = system.out;  //now both variable point to same object
john.println();     //instead of system.out.println()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`System.out`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) is a static instance of a PrintStream object.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you have a field of some non primitive data type, you have to inspect the class of the field, not the class that owns the field, to check for available methods.

So in this case even if the class `System` has a static field `out`, the type of that field is `PrintStream`, not `System`, which is in turn the class that owns `out`.